# Eiffel: Error: type is based on unknown class

Tags: eiffel

Trying to **implement some test cases on EWF application** with rest web services and JSON objects, I'm gettint a `Error: type is based on unknown class.` after adding my first class inheriting from `EQA_TEST_SET`

Seems pretty complicated to implement test cases for a simple `curl -v --header "Content-Type: application/json" --request POST --data '{"id":11,"name":"someName","enumerate":{"id":5}}' http://localhost:9997/someEntity` curl command! How can I do that? Where is there some example? I'm trying to copy-paste the example from `$ISE_LIBRARY/contrib/library/web/framework/ewf/wsf/tests/src/test_wsf_request.e` as a base, but for the moment....

I can find the class when browsing the dependencies as shown in screenshot, but the compiler not! strange behaviour!

### My `app_ewf_app.ecf`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<system xmlns="http://www.eiffel.com/developers/xml/configuration-1-19-0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.eiffel.com/developers/xml/configuration-1-19-0 http://www.eiffel.com/developers/xml/configuration-1-19-0.xsd" name="sit_ewf_app" uuid="0AB55F0B-014A-4775-B93F-ACC31C9300D5">
    <target name="common" abstract="true">
        <file_rule>
            <exclude>/CVS$</exclude>
            <exclude>/EIFGENs$</exclude>
            <exclude>/\.svn$</exclude>
        </file_rule>
        <option warning="true">
            <assertions precondition="true" postcondition="true" check="true" invariant="true" loop="true" supplier_precondition="true"/>
        </option>
        <capability>
            <catcall_detection support="none"/>
            <concurrency support="scoop"/>
            <void_safety support="all" use="all"/>
        </capability>
        <library name="base" location="$ISE_LIBRARY\library\base\base-safe.ecf"/>
        <library name="http" location="$ISE_LIBRARY\contrib\library\network\protocol\http\http-safe.ecf"/>
        <library name="json" location="$ISE_LIBRARY\contrib\library\text\parser\json\library\json.ecf"/>
        <library name="lexical" location="$ISE_LIBRARY\contrib\library\gobo\library\lexical\library.ecf"/>
        <library name="logging" location="$ISE_LIBRARY\library\runtime\logging\logging.ecf"/>
        <library name="odbc" location="$ISE_LIBRARY\library\store\dbms\rdbms\odbc\odbc.ecf"/>
        <library name="store" location="$ISE_LIBRARY\library\store\store.ecf"/>
        <library name="time" location="$ISE_LIBRARY\library\time\time.ecf"/>
        <library name="wsf" location="$ISE_LIBRARY\contrib\library\web\framework\ewf\wsf\wsf-safe.ecf"/>
        <library name="wsf_extension" location="$ISE_LIBRARY\contrib\library\web\framework\ewf\wsf\wsf_extension.ecf"/>
        <cluster name="database" location=".\database\" recursive="true"/>
        <cluster name="entity" location=".\entity\" recursive="true"/>
        <cluster name="error" location=".\error\" recursive="true"/>
        <cluster name="handler" location=".\handler\" recursive="true"/>
        <cluster name="logger" location=".\logger\" recursive="true"/>
        <cluster name="misc" location=".\misc\" recursive="true"/>
        <cluster name="relationship" location=".\relationship\" recursive="true"/>
        <cluster name="rest" location=".\rest\" recursive="true"/>
        <cluster name="service" location=".\service\" recursive="true"/>
        <cluster name="sit-json" location=".\sit-json\" recursive="true"/>
        <!-- TESTS -->
        <cluster name="tests" location=".\tests\" recursive="true"/>
    </target>
    <target name="ewf_app_any" extends="common">
        <root class="EWF_APP" feature="make_and_launch"/>
        <capability>
            <concurrency support="scoop"/>
        </capability>
        <library name="cgi" location="$ISE_LIBRARY\contrib\library\web\framework\ewf\wsf\connector\cgi-safe.ecf"/>
        <library name="libfcgi" location="$ISE_LIBRARY\contrib\library\web\framework\ewf\wsf\connector\libfcgi-safe.ecf"/>
        <library name="standalone" location="$ISE_LIBRARY\contrib\library\web\framework\ewf\wsf\connector\standalone-safe.ecf"/>
        <cluster name="launcher" location=".\launcher\">
            <cluster name="any_launcher" location="$|any\"/>
        </cluster>
        <cluster name="src" location=".\src\" recursive="true"/>
    </target>
    <target name="ewf_app_standalone" extends="common">
        <root class="EWF_APP" feature="make_and_launch"/>
        <capability>
            <catcall_detection support="none"/>
            <concurrency support="scoop"/>
            <void_safety support="all"/>
        </capability>
        <variable name="httpd_ssl_disabled" value="true"/>
        <library name="default_standalone" location="$ISE_LIBRARY\contrib\library\web\framework\ewf\wsf\default\standalone-safe.ecf"/>
        <library name="eel" location="$ISE_LIBRARY\contrib\library\text\encryption\eel\eel.ecf"/>
        <library name="ewsgi" location="$ISE_LIBRARY\contrib\library\web\framework\ewf\ewsgi\ewsgi.ecf"/>
        <library name="http_client" location="$ISE_LIBRARY\contrib\library\network\http_client\http_client.ecf"/>
        <library name="testing" location="$ISE_LIBRARY\library\testing\testing-safe.ecf"/>
        <cluster name="launcher" location=".\launcher\">
            <cluster name="default_launcher" location="$|default\"/>
        </cluster>
        <cluster name="src" location=".\src\" recursive="true"/>
    </target>
    <target name="ewf_app_cgi" extends="common">
        <root class="EWF_APP" feature="make_and_launch"/>
        <capability>
            <concurrency support="scoop" use="none"/>
        </capability>
        <library name="default_cgi" location="$ISE_LIBRARY\contrib\library\web\framework\ewf\wsf\default\cgi-safe.ecf"/>
        <cluster name="launcher" location=".\launcher\">
            <cluster name="default_launcher" location="$|default\"/>
        </cluster>
        <cluster name="src" location=".\src\" recursive="true"/>
    </target>
    <target name="ewf_app_libfcgi" extends="common">
        <root class="EWF_APP" feature="make_and_launch"/>
        <capability>
            <concurrency support="scoop" use="none"/>
        </capability>
        <library name="default_libfcgi" location="$ISE_LIBRARY\contrib\library\web\framework\ewf\wsf\default\libfcgi-safe.ecf"/>
        <cluster name="launcher" location=".\launcher\">
            <cluster name="default_launcher" location="$|default\"/>
        </cluster>
        <cluster name="src" location=".\src\" recursive="true"/>
    </target>
    <target name="ewf_app" extends="ewf_app_any">
    </target>
</system>
```

### My error

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The library `testing` should be added to the list of libraries of the target for which you want to run tests. The presence of the class `EQA_TEST_SET` in the system does not mean it is automatically available to the class `TEST_WSF_REQUEST`. The corresponding library should be included explicitly.

Comment: but it stands on my ewf_standalone target ! isn't it?

Comment: what is strange for me is that when I include it into common the compilation error disappears, but it doesn't seem to be found when I add it to the current target I'm using!

Comment: @Pipo The library should be added to the target with the cluster containing your class.